# Configure username/password only auth in OpenVPN Connect

Tags: openvpn, apple-ios

I'm trying to configure my client to use only username/password for authentication.
Unfortunatly, iOS app keeps asking me for a Certificate (I'm not sure it's Client certificate though).

Here is client.config:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote ...
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
ns-cert-type server
auth-user-pass
auth-retry interact
```

Here is how it looks on iOS (notice the second field asking a certificate):

[image]

Comment: Which iOS are you talking about? I guess it's the one from apple with the picture, and not the cisco one.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU see tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should read app's description on iTunes. I only had to add `setenv CLIENT_CERT 0` to my client.ovpn file.